# NLog: disable/enable multiple log files

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I have 2 loggers: one for Info messages, and another for other ones.

```
<logger name="ErrLogger" levels="Trace,Debug,Warn,Fatal,Error" writeTo="logfile_w" />
<logger name="InfoLogger" level="Info" writeTo="logfile_i" />
```

Each one write information to his own file.
Is it possible in runtime turn off and on certain loggers?

Btw, for each class I'm using code like this:

```
private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

And then in functions I use `_logger.Info("message");`. Should I modify class loggers too?

Comment: Seems to me like you chose a bad design. Eventually - you are the one who writes to the log, so you should decide weather to call the `_logger.Log(...)` or not.

Comment: Yes, but I'm creating ClassLibrary, so info log will be usefull for users and error log for developers. And when developers made application - error log will be turned off.

Comment: That's why you have the app.config. when you release your application - release it with the proper logs turned on, and when you're developing - with the proper logs turned off (or vice versa)

Comment: BTW, that's why you have the *app.debug.config* and *app.release.config*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filtering for that.

Example

```
<rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="file">
        <filters>
            <when condition="${logger}==loggername" action="Ignore" />

        </filters>
    </logger>
</rules>
```

See [filtering on NLog wiki](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/When-filter) and the [`${logger}` layout renderer](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logger-Layout-Renderer).

Hint: not sure what the (full) name of the logger is? Just log something with `${logger}` and check the logs.